# Is a monotone function with infinite discontinuous point integrable?

Tags: analysis

I know that if a function is monotone in $[a,b]$ it's Riemann integrable.  My question is :
if a monotone function in $[a,b]$ has infinite discontinuity points is still Riemann integrable ? And why ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A monotone function in $[a,b]$ with infinitely many discontinuity points is monotone in $[a,b]$. If a function is monotone in $[a,b]$, it is Riemann integrable. Therefore a monotone function in $[a,b]$ with infinitely many discontinuity points is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Nice . But why a function with infinite discontinuity point is Riemann Integrable

Comment: It doesn't say that an *arbitrary* function with infinitely many discontinuities is Riemann integrable. It says that a *monotonous* one is. And it is because it is monotonous.